# JsonObjectRequest Synchronisation?

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I have to make several requests to an API for an Android App and I am having the following problem:
I have a list of items and I have to make a request for each in order to get some data and show it in the app. When my list's size is 1 (in case I have only one item), the app works perfectly but if I have more I get the data mixed and one item have the value of other and things like that.

I am using JsonObjectRequest and Volley. I use callback interfaces for sending back the request data to the activities. I think it's probably a synchronisation problem but I'm not sure and I'm a bit frustrated. I've tried everything!

- Request Code:

  ```
  JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlMarket, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


              try {
                  JSONObject singleResult;
                  singleResult = response.getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(0);
                  coin.setHigh(singleResult.getDouble("High"));
                  coin.setLow(singleResult.getDouble("Low"));
                  coin.setLast(singleResult.getDouble("Last"));
                  coin.setVolInBtc(singleResult.getDouble("BaseVolume"));
                  coin.setBid(singleResult.getDouble("Bid"));
                  coin.setAsk(singleResult.getDouble("Ask"));
                  coin.setPrevDay(singleResult.getString("PrevDay"));

                  callback.onSuccess(coin);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

          }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              error.printStackTrace();
          }
      });

      requestQueue.add(request);
  ```

Any kind of help would be appreciated!!

PD.: if there's a better way for doing that instead of JsonObjectRequest, please tell me!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Puneet I've posted the request code!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider either of these two options:

1. Extend JSONObjectRequest that accepts a id/token field which is returned as part of the Success/Error callback.
2. Use a final field as an identifier before you make an API call. Assuming you are making these calls in a loop, you can then refer to this final field from your anonymous callbacks to identify the specific Stock. For example, you can use the ISIN, database ID or ticker symbol to identify the response.

Comment: Based on your code, you are making multiple requests for stock prices. You must be using some sort of ID (example: Ticker Symbol, Database ID, ISIN, etc). The solution I proposed was to store that ID as part of the request and return it with the response so that you know which stock was associated with the response. I hope that clarifies.